# How to implement Admob in my Game in libGDX?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am start working with libGDX and I want to use  the AdMob in my Game.

If someone have already worked on it, Give me the way to make this thing happen in the Game ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, adMObid );

    View gameView=initializeForView(new TalkingFriendApp(this), cfg);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    layout.addView(gameView, adParams);
    layout.addView(adView, adParams1);

    setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: where I add to use this code in my Main.java which extends ApplicationListener or In Android.java which extends AndroidApplication

Comment: This Is For Admob or MobClix ?

Comment: in android project in onCreate()
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {}

This is for AdMob Banner Add

Comment: I did this as you write but I am not able to import AdView / AdSize .

Comment: I read on the libGdx , this file is mention for that             import com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixAdView; I add the mobclix.jar in my Android project but could not import the AdView/AdSize

Comment: import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;


U need to add admob.jar which u can get from google

Comment: Now I am getting the banner but it having a error like : you must have add an AdActivity declare in AndroidManifeast.xml. What is this ?

Comment: put it in your manifest

        <!-- admob -->
<activity      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" >
</activity>

Comment: thanks for the help... :) And I want to know one more thing is "Except Admob and Mobclix what kind add I am able to implement in the libgdx"

Comment: all the adds compatible for android

Comment: It means I have to follow their step  for the implementation .

Comment: yupp all codeing part is to be done on android side.

And just in case u need any callback in ur libgdx side u can do it via a interface in libgdx which is implemented by a class in android

Answer (score 1):

for integrating in your app [See Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130801050713/http://www.michenux.net/android-admob-tutorial-461.html)

```
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "YourID");        
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ad);        
    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(false);
    adView.loadAd(request);
```

Comment: is this for Admob or MobClix??

Comment: this is for Admob for app

Comment: in Manifeast.xml . I add to something for the admob

Comment: but we have new admob, how to integrate the version 6.4.1?