# LibGDX and Admob: I don't see the ads

Tags: java, android, admob, libgdx

I tried everything, the code works without errors but i don't see my ads. On my admob account there is no request also...

Here is my code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  View gameView = initializeForView(new com.me.game.App(), false);
  AdView adView = createAdView();
  RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE);
  LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  layout.addView(adView, adParams);
  layout.addView(gameView, layoutParams);
  setContentView(layout);
  startAdvertising(adView);
}

private AdView createAdView() {
  AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER,"PUBLISHER_ID");
  return adView;
}

private void startAdvertising(AdView adView) {
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
  adRequest.addTestDevice("A0FA8C8161016266010B4E4239CD92D5"); // My Test Device
  adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Admob in my Game in libGDX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985828/how-to-implement-admob-in-my-game-in-libgdx)

Comment: Add gameview after adview. This will work for you

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the gameview after the ad view. Also for better control, better do it like this:

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the background color of your AdView to transparent?

```
adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```